# Segmentation fault in program using linked list

Tags: c

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct details{
  char *name;
  int no;
  struct details *info;
};

//ADDING THE LINKED LIST
void add(struct details **info,int no,char * name){
  struct details *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct details));
  temp = *info;
  if(temp == NULL){
      temp = malloc(sizeof(struct details));
  }
  else{
    if(temp->info == NULL){
       temp->info = malloc(sizeof(struct details));
       temp = temp->info;
    }
  }
  temp->no = no;
  temp->name = name;
}

//DISPLAYING THE LINKED LIST
void display(struct details *info){
  while(info!=NULL){
    printf("\nThe List is:\n","\n no: \tname:\n","%d","%s and link:%d",info->no,info->name,info->info);
    info = info->info;
  }
}

//MAIN PROGRAM
int main()
{
 struct details* ptr;
 char *name,ch;
 int no;
 int select_option;
 ptr = NULL;
 printf("\n   ***MAIN MENU***   \n1.Add Element \n2.Delete Element \n3.Search Element \n4.Linked List Concatenation \n5.Invert Linked List \n6.Diplay Elements \n Please Enter your choice:(eg:1,2,3,4,5,6)\n");
 scanf("%d",&select_option);
do{
 switch(select_option){
   case 1:
        printf("Enter no to add:");
        scanf("%d",&no);
        printf("Enter name to add:");
        scanf("%s",name);
        add(&ptr,no,name);
        break;
   case 6:
        display(ptr);
        break;
   default:
        printf("INVALID CHOICE!");
        break;
 }
 printf("Do u wish to continue?(y/n):");
 scanf("%c",&ch);
}while(ch == 'y' || ch == 'y');
 return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to write a simple program using a linked list to add and display data. But its throwing me a segmentation fault. I hope that I have initialized all the pointers with the memory. All help appreciated.

Comment: (gdb) run 10
Starting program: /home/beata/linked_List/p1/linked_list 10

   ***MAIN MENU***   
1.Add Element 
2.Delete Element 
3.Search Element 
4.Linked List Concatenation 
5.Invert Linked List 
6.Diplay Elements 
 Please Enter your choice:(eg:1,2,3,4,5,6)
1
Enter no to add:12
Enter name to add:beata

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00178d98 in _IO_vfscanf () from /lib/libc.so.6 when debugged i could nnot get the proper information

Comment: That is NOT how you use a debugger.   Find someone who can give you a demonstration of stepping through the code and examining variables.

Comment: thanks will ask someone to help me with the debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
temp->name = name;
```

does not copy `name` to `temp->name` but assigns `temp->name` to the same address as `name`, which is local to the function. You need to `malloc()` and `strcpy()`:

```
temp->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(temp->name, name);
```

Remember to `free(temp->name);` when no longer required.

Additionally (as pointed out by Luchian), when reading from `stdin`:

```
char *name;
...
scanf("%s",name);
```

`name` has no memory allocated to. Declare it as an array but you need to protect against writing beyond the end of it:

```
char name[128];
...
scanf("%127s",name);
```

Comment: You could always use `strdup` and save yourself the malloc call.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, yep but AFAIK, `strdup` is not part of the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't:

```
char *name;
///....
scanf("%s",name);
```

You never allocated memory for `name`.

You could do `char name[50];` or whatever, but beware of overflows. Guard against them.

Comment: Thakns for remembering that. will be aware whenever i am handling arrays

Answer (score 1):

Both **hmjd** and **Luchian Grigore** answers are a prior problems, but also:

You don't initialize `temp->info` at any point after a `malloc`, so it is never `NULL`, but yet `temp->info` is an invalid address.

Either initialize it explicitly or use `calloc`, which initializes the allocated buffer, instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate `name`

```
     char *name
```